# Will the tcp connections between two applications on the same Linux machine ever disconnect

Tags: database, linux, tcp

I am using a connection pool to connect to a database on the same Linux machine. I want to be absolutely sure that the connection I get from the connection pool is valid. I am now testing the connection on borrowing but theoretically the tcp connection can still disconnect between the validation and the actual request. Additionally, testing before each request hurts latency and throughput.

How about using a file socket? Will it ever disconnect?

Update: I am wondering if the connection could be broken at the networking layer. Is it true that only the app or the DB can actively end the connection?

Answer (score 0):

> I am now testing the connection on borrowing but theoretically the tcp connection can still disconnect between the validation and the actual request.

True but unlikely.

> Additionally, testing before each request hurts latency and throughput.

(1) Only if you are borrowing a new connection for each request. (2) Have you measured the 'hurt'?

> How about using a file socket? Will it ever disconnect?

You certainly can't assume that it won't. The database end may close it on idle, for example.

Comment: To prevent the connections from timing out at the database end, I can test them periodically when they are idle in the connection pool (DB timeout is configurable).